# How to calc data transfer size for a port with node.js?

Tags: monitoring, port, network-monitoring

I developing a node.js program,
I want know how much data transfered per port, but i didnt found native node.js solution, there is thired party program, if thay have api,it can be usefull, can you suggest some solution for it?